# How to display pop box on the point of click - CSS

Tags: css

how to display pop box on the point of click

here is my css code display the pop, just wanted to pop on clicking position.

```
.popupboxwrapper{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:30%;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;  
    z-index:1500;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background:#000;
}

.popupbox{
    top:50px;
    left:35%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width:auto;
    z-index:1501;   
    opacity:2 !important;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-sizing:border-box;  
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;  
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;  
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:#111 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

regards,

Comment: Please include your HTML, and also tell us what you have tried already to fix this yourself

Comment: i have changed the question i want pop box opens on the point of click

Comment: (1) You still didn't include your HTML and (2) you are clearly not even trying to solve this yourself before asking the question

Comment: (3) don't edit a question into a completely different question.  Accept the correct answer and create a new question or do a little research first...

Comment: not allowing me to post such a big html

Answer (score 2):

On your `popupboxwrapper` change the position to `position:fixed;`

BTW, on popupbox `opacity:2 !important;` makes no sense since opacity has values from 0-1.

Comment: no doesn't work its keep scrolling back content and keeping this pop on one position. i want this one to scroll up and down too..

Comment: Then you'll need to post a complete code example including your HTML in your question. BTW, your comment contradicts your question where you say "should not move on scrolling down and up".

Comment: i have changed the question i want pop box opens on the point of click---

Comment: @Reel That is completely different from what you originally wanted.... You should have accepted the answer and created a new question IMO... (Considering j08691 answered exactly what you wanted originally)

Comment: thats why i inform respected j08691